# python pyfiglet not installing due to NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

[package not installing due to NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzL0V.png)

can anyone know how to fix this? I tried to install "python install pyfiglet" in cmd with the same directory as the program file with, but it says CAN'T OPEN FILE AND NO SUCH FILE DIRECTORY

Comment: What is "the"? Maybe try *python -m pip install pyfiglet*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, when you type `python install figlet` at the command prompt, what do you expect it to do? **Why**? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to make sure you understand installing things in Python, for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+do+I+install+packages+in+python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `python` command is designed to run Python code, not to install Python modules.

What you are looking for is `pip`, which is the official package manager, made for installing Python modules hosted on [PyPI](https://pypi.org), and with some hacks, online community sources:

```
python -m pip install pyfiglet
```

If Python detects the `pip` module as non-existent, which is useful in many cases (like installations that did not install `pip`), use the [built-in `ensurepip` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) to install it:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Hope this resolved your problem.